# Passing context in Glide from a ViewHolder class?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

I'm trying to pass context inside `with()`, but "this" doesn't work, neither do `getContext()`, `getActivity()`. My class is a ViewHolder which extends `RecycleView`. How do I get the context?

```
protected void bind(I item, @Nullable OnContactClickListener<I> listener) {
            Author author = item.getContact().getAuthor();
            Glide.with(this /* context */)
                    .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                    .load(storageRef.child("/"+author.getName()+"/pic.jpg"))
                    .error(new IdenticonDrawable(author.getId().getBytes()))
                    .into(avatar);
            String contactName = author.getName();
            name.setText(contactName);
```

Comment: post your full code

Comment: you have to pass context from where you call your adapter either be fragment or activity.

Comment: You can pass the context via constructor . or you can use `view.getContext()`.

Comment: @Rumit , the rest of the class? it's pretty irrelevant. Hemant Parmar how do I pass context from another class?

Comment: just pass context to your adapter, show my code below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

so simple get context of avtar view.

```
protected void bind(I item, @Nullable OnContactClickListener<I> listener) {
            Author author = item.getContact().getAuthor();
            Glide.with(avatar.getContext())
                    .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                    .load(storageRef.child("/"+author.getName()+"/pic.jpg"))
                    .error(new IdenticonDrawable(author.getId().getBytes()))
                    .into(avatar);
            String contactName = author.getName();
            name.setText(contactName);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
     Glide.with(itemview)
                        .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                        .load(storageRef.child("/"+author.getName()+"/pic.jpg"))
                        .error(new IdenticonDrawable(author.getId().getBytes()))
                        .into(avatar);
```

Answer (score 1):

From this line

```
name.setText(contactName);
```

I can say name is a `TextView`. You can use `view.getContext()` to get `Context` from view. [`view.getContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext()) returns the context the view is running in.

```
Glide.with(name.getContext())
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this :

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private final Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(this.context).inflate(R.layout.frames_adapter_item, parent, false));
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {


        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {



            }
        });

        holder.progress_bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(arrayOfFile.get(position)).asBitmap().into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                    if (resource != null) {
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
                    }
                }

            });


    }

    public int getItemCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final ImageView imageView;
        final ProgressBar progress_bar;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            this.progress_bar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        }
    }
}
```